# problem to go to internal multiple elements in XML file by c#

Tags: c#, xml

I want to add a new line in below "option1 line" at my XML file by c#.my code working correctly but the only problem is my new line write out of "XmlParameters" and "RegParameters" under .
Does anybody know how to go to "XmlParameters" to writing my new line?

this is my original XML file:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<CustomConfiguraton xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xmlns:xsd="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema">
  <ConfigSection Name="Message">
    <XmlParameters>
      <XmlParam Key="OPTION1" Value="XXX" Option="" />
    </XmlParameters>
    <RegParameters>
    </RegParameters>
  </ConfigSection>
  <ConfigSection Name="Tcpip">
    <XmlParameters>
    </XmlParameters>
  </ConfigSection  
    <XmlParameters>
    </XmlParameters>
  </ConfigSection>
</CustomConfiguraton>
```

I want to add a line under Option1 in it.
additional line is :

```
<XmlParam Key="OPTION2" Value="XXX" Option="" />
```

finally, I want to have this XML file:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<CustomConfiguraton xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xmlns:xsd="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema">
  <ConfigSection Name="Message">
    <XmlParameters>
      <XmlParam Key="OPTION1" Value="XXX" Option="" />
      <XmlParam Key="OPTION2" Value="XXX" Option="" />
    </XmlParameters>
    <RegParameters>
    </RegParameters>
  </ConfigSection>
  <ConfigSection Name="Tcpip">
    <XmlParameters>
    </XmlParameters>
  </ConfigSection  
    <XmlParameters>
    </XmlParameters>
  </ConfigSection>
</CustomConfiguraton>
```

I try this code but the result is not the same as the things I want and the line added in the end of "ConfigSection Name="Message" and out of "XmlParameters" and "XmlParameters"

```
const string FILENAME = @"E:\Config.xml";
XDocument doc = XDocument.Load(FILENAME);

XElement type2 = doc.Descendants("ConfigSection").Where(x => (string)x.Attribute("Name") == "Message").FirstOrDefault();

type2.Add(new XElement("XmlParam", new XAttribute("Key", "OPTION2"), new XAttribute("Value", "XXX"), new XAttribute("Option", "")));
doc.Save(@"E:\Config.xml");
```

Comment: [You deleted and duplicated your question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57165481/how-to-go-to-internal-multiple-elements-in-xml-file-by-c-sharp)?  The original was closed with *four duplicates*.

Answer (score 0):

this code is solving the problem

```
XElement type2 = doc.Descendants("ConfigSection").Where(x => (string)x.Attribute("Name") == "Message").Descendants("XmlParameters").LastOrDefault();
```